# htaccess combine rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 2 htaccess rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=tag&tag=$1&pg=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=tag&tag=$1&pg=$2 [L]
```

example:

1- `mysite.ext/tag/php/`

2- `mysite.ext/tag/php/13/`

Is it possible to combine the 2, knowing that the second argument which is the page number is optional as it is for pagination?

So the "pg" will be `(1|$2)` (pg=1 or pg=the-page-number)

Comment: Would not it be easier to just check in your code whether `pg` is empty and then consider it being `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"So the "pg" will be (1|$2) (pg=1 or pg=the-page-number)"*

Unfortunately it does not work like that. The best what you can do is to use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/\.]+)/?(\d+)?/?$ index.php?p=tag&tag=$1&pg=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

If `mysite.ext/tag/php/` is requested then it gets rewritten to `index.php?p=tag&tag=php&pg=`. The `pg` parameter is empty (as you can see). What you need to do -- is to put  extra bit of code in `index.php` to check if `pg` is empty then assign value of `1`:

```
$page_number = isset($_GET['pg']) ? $_GET['pg'] : '';
if (empty($page_number)) {
    $page_number = 1;
}
else {
    // convert it to INT type
    $page_number = (int)$page_number;
}
```

The code above may look as too much (too safe approach), but that's what I prefer to do (when doing e-commerce sites security is first priority). (*I've skipped the full validation to make it shorter*)

But you can make it much smaller, if you wish (you still have to validate the input data anyway):

```
$page_number = isset($_GET['pg']) ? $_GET['pg'] : '';
if (empty($page_number)) $page_number = 1;
```